# How can I verify the clocksource in my system?

Tags: linux-kernel, clock

According to the kernel code, timekeeping will initialize the clocksource as jiffies.

```
/*
 * timekeeping_init - Initializes the clocksource and common timekeeping values
 */
void __init timekeeping_init(void)
{
...
clock = clocksource_default_clock();
...
}

struct clocksource * __init __weak clocksource_default_clock(void)
{
    return &clocksource_jiffies;
}
```

But it also says that once a new clocksource detected, timekeeping will replace it.

```
/**
 * timekeeping_notify - Install a new clock source
 * @clock:      pointer to the clock source
 *
 * This function is called from clocksource.c after a new, better clock
 * source has been registered. The caller holds the clocksource_mutex.
 */
```

Now I know that when I input command "date" it will eventually get the system time from clocksource. I want know that which clocksource am I using then, is that jiffies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.

The clocksource can be found in the path below:

```
/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0
```

As it shows:

```
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Jul 30 16:24 available_clocksource
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Jul 30 16:32 current_clocksource
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    0 Jul 30 16:24 power
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Jul 28 11:40 subsystem -> ../../../../bus/clocksource
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Jul 28 11:40 uevent
--w-------. 1 root root 4096 Jul 30 16:24 unbind_clocksource
```

`available_clocksource` shows all the available clocksources.

`current_clocksource` shows clocksource system is using currently.

Using `echo xxx > current_clocksource` can change current clocksource(`jiffies` is the default clocksource and not in `available_clocksource`, but it can't be set.it seems that the system doesn't allow a non-highres capable clocksource to be set) .